# Elementary derivation of max/min of quadratic trig polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, optimization

Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ be fixed real numbers, and $x$ a variable in $[0,\pi)$.  Consider the expression

\begin{equation}
(\alpha^2+\beta^2)\cos^2(x) + 2(\alpha\gamma+\beta\delta)\cos(x)\sin(x) + (\gamma^2+\delta^2)\sin^2(x)
\end{equation}

Suppose it has a maximum at $x=M$ and a minimum at the point $x=m$.  How can I show $|M-m|=\pi/2$?

I can take the derivative of the expression with respect to $x$, and set it to $0$.  I see that if $y\in[0,\pi/2)$ is a zero, then so is $y+\pi/2$. I guess I could take the second derivative to show one is a max, and the other a min.  But is there some elementary way to show the difference between the two angles is $\pi/2$?

For context, this comes up when considering regular maps $f$ from a complex domain to a complex domain. There, if $J_f$ is the Jacobian of $f$ at a particular point, then

\begin{equation}
\det(J_f)^2 = Mm
\end{equation}

[The Greek letters are fixed values depending on $f$ and the point.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove that the difference is $\pi/2$ just from simple trigonometric considerations.
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}\\
\sin^2(x)=\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}\\
2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)
$$
With these equations you can rearrange the formula that you have as
$$A\cos(2x)+B\sin(2x)+C$$
where $A,B,C$ are just some constants in terms of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma,\delta$. The constant term is inconsequential for the minimum /maximum positions, so I am going to skip it. You can rewrite what is left as
$$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left(\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\cos(2x)+\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\sin(2x)\right)$$ I chose to write the expression in such a way because I can have now an angle $\phi$ such as $\sin(\phi)=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and $\cos(\phi)=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$, so my function becomes
$$\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\left(\sin(\phi)\cos(2x)+\cos(\phi)\sin(2x)\right)=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\sin(2x+\phi)$$
The distance between minima and maxima for the $\sin$ function is $\pi$, but since you have $2x$ in your expression, the distance reduces to $\pi/2$

Comment: Awesome, thanks!